# Kingo rooted my phone, windows laptop died

Tags: 4.4-kitkat, lg, unrooting, att

Now running Ubuntu 14.04 on my main computer; my windows laptop that i ran kingo root on to root the phone died, my LG G Vista is due for the lollipop upgrade from version 4.4.2 and it will not let me do the upgrade while its rooted. Is their a way to UN-root it using a different method even though i rooted it with the app so i can do the upgrade? I tried running kingo root in the wine emulator and it seemed to run fine it just didn't see my phone through the usb even though it was plugged in and on debugging mode. Any help is appreciated and thank you in advance!

Comment: Can't you just unroot from within the Superuser app?

Comment: @SuperThomasLab Some root apps, although allowing unroot, do not fix the "system modified" problem.

Answer (score 0):

Alright. You are going to need:

- Your device + cable
- the stock ROM (Download [here](http://www.lg-phones.org/official-verizon-lg-g-vista-vs880-firmware-rom.html)
- adb (ill help you install that)

Ok, heres what to do:

1. plug in your phone in usb debugging mode(in developer options. if not there, go to about device and tap build number 7 times, then back once.)
2. open terminal, and do`sudo apt-get install adb` remember to put in your password!
3. in terminal, do `cd /home/<username>/downloads`
4. boot your device into recovery mode (you made need to look up how, it varies on device) and choose `install from adb` or similar options.
5. in the terminal, do `adb sideload <name of ROM file, include the extension.>`
   Wait dor it to finish, and you will be updated!!
6. Boot your device up. Charge it to full (if not already) and use the system update option. It should work.
   Enjoy your 4.4.2 :)

Comment: Does it matter that I own an at&t phone? This rom says verizon, i just wanted to make sure before starting this process.

Comment: I believe  it may.